# programmatically pop a UIViewConroller

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to go back by one UIViewController.  I have the code below but it does not work:

```
 let signUpPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegisterViewController_")
 signUpPage?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pop to a specific `ViewController`:

```
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(signUpPage, animated: true)
```

If you want to go to the previous `ViewController`:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```